# How to sort the json object with main node text in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have json object and want to sort the whole json object based on variablevalue.

JsonObject:

```
{  
   "Surveyors, Cartographers, and Photogrammetrists":[  
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":204400.0
         },
         "variablename":"Employment, 2014 (persons)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":198300.0
         },
         "variablename":"Projected 
 Employment, 2024 (persons)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":53401.018
         },
         "variablename":"Average 
 annual wage ($)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":50000.0
         },
         "variablename":"Median annual wage 
 ($)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":93.7004
         },
         "variablename":"Offshorability rank (0-100)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":77.76633
         },
         "variablename":"Male (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":70.81703333333334
         },
         "variablename":"Probability of computerisation (%)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":55.7
         },
         "variablename":"Labor Shortage Index (Education & Skills)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":34.8
         },
         "variablename":"Labor Shortage Index (Flexibility)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":23.87058222069003
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Labor Supply (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":23.456978920690027
         },
         "variablename":"Projected New Entrants  (% of 2014 employment 
)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":18.2
         },
         "variablename":"Labor Shortage Index"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":15.606653247064578
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Replacement of Jobs, 2014-2024 (% 
 of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":14.623767403
         },
         "variablename":"Average years 
 of schooling (years)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":14.0
         },
         "variablename":"Typical years 
 of schooling (years)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":12.93433
         },
         "variablename":"Immigrants 
 (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":12.622308824363992
         },
         "variablename":"Projected 
 Labor Demand (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":11.47879
         },
         "variablename":"Part-time workers (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":10.80817
         },
         "variablename":"Skill measure*"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":8.5
         },
         "variablename":"Labor Shortage Index 
 (Demand-Supply)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":5.29082
         },
         "variablename":"Teleworkers (% of 2014 
 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":2.0697345889048466
         },
         "variablename":"Unionized workers 
 (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":1.98172
         },
         "variablename":"Part-time 
 workers younger than 24 (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":1.0
         },
         "variablename":"Certification measure (0-2)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":0.4136033
         },
         "variablename":"Projected 
 Re-entrants (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":0.0
         },
         "variablename":"Typical 
 work experience  (0-2)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":0.0
         },
         "variablename":"Typical training 
 (0-6)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":-2.984344422700591
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Employment 
 Growth, 2014-2024 (%)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":-11.248273396326036
         },
         "variablename":"Projected 
 Demand-Supply gap (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":-16.71060203279864
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Demand-Supply gap (% of 2014 employment, adjusted)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":443900.0
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Employment, 2024 (persons)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":443000.0
         },
         "variablename":"Employment, 2014 (persons)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":56048.869
         },
         "variablename":"Average annual wage ($)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":50000            .0
         },
         "variablename":"Median annual wage ($)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":80.75036
         },
         "variablename":"Male (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":70.81703333333334
         },
         "variablename":"Probability of computerisation (%)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":63.3
         },
         "variablename":"Labor Shortage Index (Education & Skills)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":59.199999999999996
         },
         "variablename":"Labor Shortage Index"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":57.199999999999996
         },
         "variablename":"Labor Shortage Index (Demand-Supply)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":55.2
         },
         "variablename":"Labor 
 Shortage Index (Flexibility)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":54.9048
         },
         "variablename":"Offshorability 
 rank (0-100)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":26.00451467268623
         },
         "variablename":"Projected 
 Labor Demand (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":25.80135440180587
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Replacement of Jobs, 2014-2024 (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":18.895277715376846
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Labor Supply (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":18.481674415376844
         },
         "variablename":"Projected New Entrants  (% of 2014 employment 
)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":15.282309999999999
         },
         "variablename":"Immigrants (% of 2014 
 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":14.464026496923166
         },
         "variablename":"Unionized workers 
 (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":14.094928248999999
         },
         "variablename":"Average 
 years of schooling (years)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":14.0
         },
         "variablename":"Typical 
 years of schooling (years)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":11.00492
         },
         "variablename":"Skill 
 measure*"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":7.58775
         },
         "variablename":"Part-time workers (% of 2014 
 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":7.109236957309385
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Demand-Supply 
 gap (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":3.35128
         },
         "variablename":"Part-time 
 workers younger than 24 (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":2.049
         },
         "variablename":"Teleworkers (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":1.0
         },
         "variablename":"Certification 
 measure (0-2)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":0.4136033
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Re-entrants 
 (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":0.2031602708803648
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Employment Growth, 2014-2024 (%)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":0.0
         },
         "variablename":"Typical work experience  (0-2)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":0.0
         },
         "variablename":"Typical 
 training (0-6)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":-1.9212370833226702
         },
         "variablename":"Projected 
 Demand-Supply gap (% of 2014 employment, adjusted)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":57299.999237
         },
         "variablename":"Employment, 2014 (persons)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":52900.001526
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Employment, 2024 (persons)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":50277.343
         },
         "variablename":"Average annual wage ($)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":45000.0
         },
         "variablename":"Median annual 
 wage ($)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":96.001
         },
         "variablename":"Probability of computerisation 
 (%)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":91.34864999999999
         },
         "variablename":"Male (% of 2014 employment 
)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":61.4
         },
         "variablename":"Labor Shortage Index (Flexibility 
)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":50.0
         },
         "variablename":"Labor Shortage Index (Education & Skills 
)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":20.375618388959438
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Labor Supply  
(% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":20.3
         },
         "variablename":"Labor Shortage Index"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":19.962015088959436
         },
         "variablename":"Projected New Entrants 
  (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":19.02268386761445
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Replacement of Jobs, 2014-2024 (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":13.730615929999999
         },
         "variablename":"Average years of schooling (years)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":12.5
         },
         "variablename":"Offshorability rank (0-100)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":12.0
         },
         "variablename":"Typical years of schooling (years)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":11.343804688574572
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Labor Demand (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":11.27454
         },
         "variablename":"Part-time workers (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":10.76173
         },
         "variablename":"Skill measure*"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":10.299999999999999
         },
         "variablename":"Labor Shortage Index (Demand-Supply)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":5.6590300000000004
         },
         "variablename":"Immigrants (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":4.123637228124855
         },
         "variablename":"Unionized workers (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":3.96216
         },
         "variablename":"Teleworkers (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":3.0
         },
         "variablename":"Typical training (0-6)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":2.1993300000000002
         },
         "variablename":"Part-time workers younger than 24 (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":0.4136033
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Re-entrants (% of 2014 employment 
)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":0.0
         },
         "variablename":"Typical work experience  (0-2)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":0.0
         },
         "variablename":"Certification measure (0-2)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":-7.6788791790398765
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Employment Growth, 2014-2024 (%)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":-9.031813700384866
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Demand-Supply gap (% of 2014 employment 
)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":-15.689753054049923
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Demand-Supply 
 gap (% of 2014 employment, adjusted)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":59299.999237
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Employment, 2024 (persons)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":58259.97
         },
         "variablename":"Average annual wage ($)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":56599.998474
         },
         "variablename":"Employment 
, 2014 (persons)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":50000.0
         },
         "variablename":"Median annual wage 
 ($)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":90.10000000000001
         },
         "variablename":"Labor Shortage Index  
(Flexibility)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":82.74463
         },
         "variablename":"Male (% of 2014 employment 
)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":79.3
         },
         "variablename":"Labor Shortage Index"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":72.8
         },
         "variablename":"Labor Shortage Index (Education & Skills)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":59.8
         },
         "variablename":"Labor Shortage Index (Demand-Supply)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":37.45583274660072
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Labor Demand (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":32.685513248729556
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Replacement of Jobs, 2014-2024 
 (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":27.859418869633
         },
         "variablename":"Projected 
 Labor Supply (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":26.516515869633
         },
         "variablename":"Projected New Entrants  (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":19.9168
         },
         "variablename":"Probability of computerisation (%)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":16.048081623
         },
         "variablename":"Average years of schooling (years)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":16.0
         },
         "variablename":"Typical 
 years of schooling (years)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":12.5
         },
         "variablename":"Offshorability 
 rank (0-100)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":10.97879
         },
         "variablename":"Skill measure*"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":9.59849
         },
         "variablename":"Part-time workers (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":9.59641387696772
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Demand-Supply gap (% of 2014 employment 
)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":6.93850826190742
         },
         "variablename":"Unionized workers (% of 2014 
 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":5.74764
         },
         "variablename":"Teleworkers (% of 2014 
 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":5.03074
         },
         "variablename":"Immigrants (% of 2014 
 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":4.770319497871167
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Employment 
 Growth, 2014-2024 (%)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":1.342903
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Re-entrants 
 (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":1.30934
         },
         "variablename":"Part-time workers 
 younger than 24 (% of 2014 employment)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkOrange",
            "y":1.0
         },
         "variablename":"Certification measure (0-2)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"DarkRed",
            "y":0.782686
         },
         "variablename":"Typical 
 work experience  (0-2)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":0.0
         },
         "variablename":"Typical training 
 (0-6)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":-1.8435157600876302
         },
         "variablename":"Projected Demand-Supply 
 gap (% of 2014 employment, adjusted)"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have tried with function

```
 function sortByKey(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
        return ((x > y) ? -1 : ((x < y) ? 1 : 0));
    });
}
```

But it returns the inner json objects only and miss the main node text like :

```
{  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":204400.0
         },
         "variablename":"Employment, 2014 (persons)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":198300.0
         },
         "variablename":"Projected 
 Employment, 2024 (persons)"
      }
```

so final result after sorting would be like :

```
 "Surveyors, Cartographers, and Photogrammetrists":[  
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Blue",
            "y":204400.0
         },
         "variablename":"Employment, 2014 (persons)"
      },
      {  
         "variablevalue":{  
            "color":"Black",
            "y":198300.0
         },
         "variablename":"Projected 
 Employment, 2024 (persons)"
      }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: What arguments are you passing to `sortByKey(array, key)` to get this result?

Comment: @T J :I have convert json object into array then pass the converted array and key is variablevalue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to sort in descending-order by `variablevalue.y` value and it is never `null` or `undefined`.

try

```
obj["Surveyors, Cartographers, and Photogrammetrists"].sort(function(a,b){
  return parseFloat(b.variablevalue.y) - parseFloat(a.variablevalue.y);
});
```

If `variablevalue.y` can be `null`, `undefined` or `NaN` then

```
obj["Surveyors, Cartographers, and Photogrammetrists"].sort(function(a,b){
  var by = !isNaN(parseFloat(b.variablevalue.y)) || 0;
  var ay = !isNaN(parseFloat(a.variablevalue.y)) || 0;
  return by - ay;
});
```